# Node Kafka - Duplicate messages are coming

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am getting duplicate messages while consuming Kafka messages using a consumer group.

I am using this Nodejs library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node

My consumer code is given below

```
const config = require( '../../configs' );
const kafka = require( 'kafka-node' );

var options = {
    id: 'consumer1',
    kafkaHost: config.kafka.prod.kafka_host, //multiple kafka hosts (comma separated)
    groupId: "test-group2",
    sessionTimeout: 15000,
    protocol: ['roundrobin'],
    fromOffset: 'earliest'
};

var consumerGroup = new kafka.ConsumerGroup( options, 'my-replicated-topic3' );

consumerGroup.on( 'message', function ( message ) {
    console.log( message );
} );
```

I am getting below result.

```
{ topic: 'my-replicated-topic3',
  value: '{"meta":{"topic":"my-replicated-topic3","added_at":"2019-02-22T09:25:54.708Z","server":"cron"},"data":"1550827554708 ::: Totam quis qui. Sit dolore laboriosam odio. Facilis porro et quam repellat pariatur. Ad voluptatem quidem."}',
  offset: 8941,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 8966,
  key: null }
  ---
  ---
  ---
  ---
  { topic: 'my-replicated-topic3',
  value: '{"meta":{"topic":"my-replicated-topic3","added_at":"2019-02-22T09:25:54.708Z","server":"cron"},"data":"1550827554708 ::: Totam quis qui. Sit dolore laboriosam odio. Facilis porro et quam repellat pariatur. Ad voluptatem quidem."}',
  offset: 8941,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 8970,
  key: null }
```

You can see that the same message is repeated after every few records. Here **offset** of the message is same but **highWaterOffset** is different all the repeated messages.

Kindly suggest the way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you re-instantiate your consumer ? How does your consumer commit its offsets ?

By default, your consumer automatically commits its offset every 5 seconds. This is the case with your library.

If you re-instantiate your consumer before committing offset, it will restart from the last committed offset.

Comment: Hi, I am neither resetting nor committing the offset, the code posted above is the full code for consuming the data. I am starting consuming data by running the code in the terminal and I can see duplicate issue immediately.